# Custom Symbol in UINT8 - how to convert to C#?

Tags: c#, c, symbols

I have the following symbol which is a ! written in C++:

```
const UINT8 ras[1][28] ={ {0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00} }; //'!'
```

Now I need to create this in C# as a symbol and print it on a console or image, how is that possible?

I know it is supposed to print a !. But how do I got from my array to !?

Comment: What do you mean with 'symbol' here?

Comment: Are C++, C# and C in scope of this question??

Comment: The example above creates an ! when converted. But I have no idea on how to convert it. I don't even know what the array "is". It is written in C/C++ and I need to use it in C#, so yes

Comment: Then you should take a look at the C/C++ code that uses array. What you have posted is just a bunch of bytes that could be interpreted in a myriad ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a 16x14-pixel bitmap. If we take the bytes two by two, we get:

```
0x00, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00
```

Now, the binary pattern for the value `0x30` is `00110000`, so it looks like an exclamation point with a 2x2-pixel dot, and a 2x8-pixel vertical part, like so (keeping only the left-most byte, since the right-most on each line is 0 or blank):

```
00000000
00110000
00110000
00000000
00000000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00000000
```

Obviously, it's also up-side down. Using the above information, you should be able to create e.g. a plain old `Bitmap` and initialize it so you get something you eventually display in C#. Of course, that sounds a bit round-about for this very simplistic image, but still.

To initialize the Bitmap, you would do something like:

```
byte[] input = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

glyph = new Bitmap(16, 14, System.Drawing.Imaging.Format1bppIndexed);
for(int y = 0; y < glyph.Height; y++)
{
  int input_y = (glyph.Height - 1) - y; // Flip it right side up.
  for(int x = 0; x < glyph.Width; x++)
  {
    bool on = input[2 * input_y + x / 8] & (0x80 >> (x % 8));
    glyph.SetPixel(x, y, on ? System.Drawing.Color.Black : System.Drawing.Color.White);
  }
}
```

Note that this code is very rough, I'm really not a C# developer. Treat it as pseudo-code.

Comment: +1 for the "Obviously, it's also up-side down" comment. Somehow that reminded me of Sherlock Holmes. You had a byte array to look at and you end with obviously, its a '!' upside down :P

Comment: unwind that seems VERY correct. Can you give me a lead on how to actually create the writeablebitmap and initialize it?

Comment: I will create a new thread with how to actually create a bitmap from the symbol
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413701/create-bitmap-from-binary-data