# Create bitmap from binary data

Tags: c#, bitmap, binary, pixel

I have the following:

```
byte[] pixels = new byte[28] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

This is an upside down exclamation mark like this:

```
0x00, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x30, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00
```

Which in binary is:

```
00000000    00000000
00110000    00000000
00110000    00000000
00000000    00000000
00000000    00000000
00110000    00000000
00110000    00000000
00110000    00000000
00110000    00000000
00110000    00000000
00110000    00000000
00110000    00000000
00110000    00000000
00000000    00000000
```

I need to convert this to a bitmap / create a bitmap. So the exclamation mark is white and the background is black. I need to be able to color the pixels also.

How to do this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all your images are 16x14

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(16, 14);
int line=0;

for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<8; j++)
    {
        if (((pixels[i] >> j) & 1) == 1)
        {
            bmp.SetPixel( (i%2)*8 + 7-j, line, Color.Black);
        }
    }
    if(i%2==1) line++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading [Wikipedia about BMP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). You will need this to make sure that your array contains necessary meta data (e.g width and height). After making those changes you can use something like this

```
public static Bitmap ToBitmap(byte[] byteArray)
{
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
   {
     var img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
     return img;
   }
}
```

Comment: parameter is not valid exception on this line: var img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to create a bitmap that looks similar to what's inside your byte array (your "exclamation mark").

You can create a bitmap from scratch, and using some loops, simply set pixels in your `Bitmap`. Here's a simple example that draws random white pixels on a black background. Adapt it to meet your requirements:

```
Bitmap zz = new Bitmap(100, 100);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(zz))
{
    // Draws a black background
    g.Clear(Color.Black);
}

Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < zz.Height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < zz.Width; j++)
    {
        // Randomly add white pixels
        if (rnd.NextDouble() > 0.5)
        {
            zz.SetPixel(i, j, Color.White);
        }
    }
}

zz.Save(@"C:\myfile.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: I need an algorithm to do it correct. I have many symbols, not just this one, so the algorithme is important.
Works to draw on bitmaps, so thats a step on the way. Need an algorithm to figure out though